# How do I get the value of the Taxonomy Term Description after loading Taxonomy Vocabulary term by Term ID?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

What would be the best way to render the Taxonomy Vocabulary Term description value? I can render the term id and label/title, but the description seems to need something else that I'm not quite getting.

```
  // Render ID - working
  $termID = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(419)->id();
  
  // Render Label/Title - working
  $termLabel = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(419)->label();
  
  // Not sure how to get the description of the taxonomy term - not working
  $termDescription = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(419)->description();
```

Comment: In future when you report something is not working, it helps to include information about what occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is [getDescription](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermInterface.php/function/TermInterface%3A%3AgetDescription/9.4.x).

Comment: This is what I tried also and this doesn't provide a value. Is there an alternate way of writing this that would use getDescription instead? 


 ```$termDescription = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load(419)->getDescription();```

Comment: Nevermind.. I'm an idiot. getDescription worked great!